# Persist download progress angularjs buffered response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, download, buffer

I am downloading some file with $http which is calling java rest API, it responds in buffered array. I have to persist the download even if the browser reloaded. I am not sure whether it is possible or not within the client side itself.

Here is my code :

```
        $http({
          url : downloadUrl,
          method : 'POST',
          data : {filePath : path},
          cache:   true,
          headers : {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/zip'
          },
          eventHandlers: {
            progress: function (e) {
              console.log('Progress :'+((e.loaded / 
              itemSelected.fileSize) * 100));
            }
          },
          responseType : 'arraybuffer'
        }).then(function (res) {
          var blob = new Blob([res.data], {type:"application/octet-
        stream"});
          var filename = test.zip;
       // using filesaver to download the file from blob
          FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
        }, function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

Comment: why don't let browser handle download progress? It already support handle reset/reload?

Comment: @VuQuyet Cause I need to display progress included in webUI, that is the reason we are not doing it directly via browser.

Comment: @VuQuyet Also please suggest how can I handle the download progress via browser as the response could be sized upto 2-3gb.